# Node-sass on macOS Catalina not working. How should I fix this?

Tags: reactjs, macos, node-sass

I ran the `create-react-app` and then ran `yarn install` following that when I run `yarn start` my terminal prints out the following error and I have no idea for where to begin debugging this issue.

```
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (72)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.11.0
```

Comment: I had the same problem. You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67778126/6846888) how to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to upgrade to at least node-sass 4.12 for Node 12 support https://github.com/sass/node-sass#supported-nodejs-versions-vary-by-release-please-consult-the-releases-page-below-is-a-quick-guide-for-minimum-support

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install node-sass --save-dev

npm install
```