# error /node_modules/node-sass: Command failed

Tags: node.js, vue.js, yarnpkg

When I tried install vue store front in my local but when I tried "yarn install" command I get following error. How can I solve this error? How can I solve this error?

```
error /var/www/html/vue-storefront/node_modules/node-sass: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node scripts/build.js
Arguments: 
Directory: /var/www/html/vue-storefront/node_modules/node-sass
Output:
Building: /usr/bin/node /var/www/html/vue-storefront/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   '/usr/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/var/www/html/vue-storefront/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@13.9.0 | linux | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "/usr/bin/python3.6" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python3.6
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/python3.6 -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack 
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:303:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1026:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-88-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/var/www/html/vue-storefront/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/html/vue-storefront/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v13.9.0
```

Comment: It's failing because python3 is used here.
Create a `.npmrc` file in the project folder containing `python = "/usr/bin/python2.7"` and install.
According to [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp/v/3.8.0#on-unix), python 3.x.x is not yet supported.

Comment: Hi @NaceurBouhamed, I tried it but it's not working and giving same error

Comment: I got the same issue on node alpine image, if it helps https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/282

Comment: node is the crappiest technology ever for developing :D Starting project is always a nightmare of manually fixing dependencies.

Answer (score 378):

I had the same problem and I solved with the steps:

1. If your are on Apple M1 Chip, run Terminal with `Rosetta 2` (optional, only necessary if you have the Node installed with Rosetta)
2. Check your `node-sass` version in your `package.json` and compare with the following table:

| NodeJS | Supported node-sass version | Node Module |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Node 20 | 9.0+ | 115 |
| Node 19 | 8.0+ | 111 |
| Node 18 | 8.0+ | 108 |
| Node 17 | 7.0+, <8.0 | 102 |
| Node 16 | 6.0+ | 93 |
| Node 15 | 5.0+ | 88 |
| Node 14 | 4.14+ | 83 |
| Node 13 | 4.13+, <5.0 | 79 |
| Node 12 | 4.12+ | 72 |
| Node 11 | 4.10+, <5.0 | 67 |
| Node 10 | 4.9+, <6.0 | 64 |
| Node 8 | 4.5.3+, <5.0 | 57 |
| Node <8 | <5.0 | <57 |

3. Check your Node version with: `node --version`
4. Install the Nodejs version according with your `node-sass`, if your are using NVM, run: `nvm use DESIRED_VERSION`
5. Clean old `node_modules` deleting the folder or type this on terminal: `rm -rf node_modules`
6. Run: `npm install`

Resource:

- [NPM node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass)

Comment: I am running Angular and updating my node-sass in package.json to 6.0.1 to match my node 16... that did the trick.

Comment: Thanks! that was a good hint. I had to downgrade my node version and it worked.

Comment: Thanks Angelo! i downgraded my node from 17 to 13 and now it runs. I'm waiting until the day Rails 7 is out and we get rid of that webpacker! seems that node-sass is not the only one old package on it

Comment: Using bootstrap-npm-starter.  Upgraded node-sass in package.json to ^6.0.0 did the trick!  Thank you.

Comment: Depends a  lot on which context you need it. My Vue.js solution didn't run `npm i` with node  16 and I had to downgrade it to node 14. Thanks for the post!

Comment: thanks a lot. you  should  check  node version ( node -v ) then install  equivalent node-sass version according above table. In my case I   constrained to downgrade node from 16 to 14

Comment: If you are on Rails 6 you might be using Webpacker (@rails/webpacker) 5.4.3 or below. This gem includes node-sass as a dependency stuck to version ^4.14.1, so you won't see it directly in `package.json` but you will find it as a dependency of @rails/webpacker in `package.json-lock`. As according to this correct answer, you would then need to use the lower version of Node (14) to be compatible.

Comment: In this answer, the "+" symbols are incorrect-- they imply that later versions of Node are backward compatible, but they are not, leading precisely to the original issue: If you are on node-sass v 5.0, you need to downgrade to Node 15. If you are on node-sass v 4, you need to downgrade to Node 14, etc

Comment: I'm not the author of this table, I got it from Node SASS NPM docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass . And the "+", for me, it's the latest small version, for example, 6.0+ can be 6.1, 6.2, ... so on, but not 7.0.

Comment: THis looks like a recurring problem forever. node_sass should at least provide a message if this happens which node version it is compatible with.

Answer (score 183):

I had the same issue upgraded the node-sass version to be the same as node version. with yarn just run:

```
yarn add node-sass
```

this will upgrade the version and fix the issue

Comment: Not working. Got "Node.js Sass version 7.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0". Need to do: `yarn remove node-sass`, `yarn add sass`.

Comment: Just `yarn add node-sass` worked good for me. Thanks

Comment: This solution worked for me. I was building VueJS application on NodeJS ver. 16.x on Ubuntu.

Comment: Tried both `node-sass`, `sass` doesn't work

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek 's solution was the only one that worked for me on an m1 mac

Answer (score 88):

I am running `Rails 6` and for some reason it was pulling `webpacker 4.3.0` which was pulling `node-sass 4.3.0` rather than `6.0.0` which is the latest as of the date of this post.

What worked for me is the following:

1. Deleting the `node_module` folder, `package-lock.json` and `yarn.lock`
2. In my `package.json`, I upgraded `rails/webpacker: 5.3.0`.
3. I then re-ran `yarn install`.
4. Then I ran `yarn add node-sass`

That worked like a charm, after trying everything else above.

I believe those were the exact steps, although to be honest I have been trying sooo many things and they didn't work and I finally got it to work so there is a possibility I may have missed a step, but I did my best to re-create it for any future frustrated soul out there.

Comment: Step 4. wasn't required in my situation

Comment: Didid't worked for me. It shows: gyp ERR! cwd /Users/reinier/src/00_private/ror/reiniergarcia/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v16.3.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0

Comment: Thank for this, it was the last step getting my project working on an  M1 Mac!

Comment: All I did was step #2 and then ran a `yarn` and that worked for me.

Comment: Simply doing steps #2 and #3 worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: step 2 solve my problem! Thanks

Answer (score 49):

Try installing sass instead of node-sass. It worked well for me.

```
yarn remove node-sass
yarn add sass
```

Comment: This should be #1 pick. node 18 is stable so downgrading to anything below is security risk as of 2023. 
Here is deeper explanation of above solution:
[http://write.w5hnews.com/u/cwSNkeLNXf#Solved-ERR!gyp-info-using-node-gyp-3.8.0-gyp-verb-which-failed-Error-not-found-python2]

Answer (score 28):

If it's a Rails project, upgrading webpacker did the job for me.

```
yarn add @rails/webpacker
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for me for a Rails 6.x project.

Comment: This is the fix the worked for me. didn't know there was a @rails/webpacker package.

Comment: after upgrading to OSX 12.5, my Rails 5.2 project fail to start, terminal shows errors of node-sass but... tried this solution fix everything, why?

Answer (score 19):

Just upgrade your **sass** version in your `yarn.lock` file.
For node 14 the appropriate version for `node-sass` is `4.14`.
So adapt to your node version.

Comment: This didn't quite get there for node 16 - my `package.json` specified `webpacker v4.3.0` and it includes node-sass as a dependency. Updating `webpacker` to `5.3.0` was the solution for me.

Answer (score 15):

I changed the node version from 16.0 to 14.x in my package.json file and it worked.

Comment: It worked for me too. I wondering why 16 is not working though.

Answer (score 10):

Solutions here don't work for me.
Until I delete the node_modules folder and yarn.lock.

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm yarn.lock
yarn instal
```

Comment: In my case it was a sub dependancy and not even listed into package.json. The issue was into yarn.lock / package-lock.json.
It seems to be a common issue when reviving projects from the github graveyard

Answer (score 8):

Faced the same issue. If you look at the error stack, it says:

```
Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/python3.6 -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
   File "<string>", line 1
     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
                                ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It's trying to use Python2 but instead uses Python3 which is not supported.

My system runs Python3 when called using the `python` command, so I fixed this by installing Python2 and aliasing it to the `python` command:

```sh
alias python=pyhton2.7
```

Comment: Hi, where did you add the above command? I'm getting the same error @RottenCandy

Comment: @Akhila run it in the shell before run the install command, or put it in the `.bashrc` or somewhere similar (if you're on Linux).

Comment: You can just use `npm config set python python2`

Comment: In my case it was looking for "python2" which I did not have. Installed python2 and it worked directly.

Answer (score 7):

Having same issue here. I did

```
nvm install 14
```

because the `node-sass` version I have in `package.json` is `4.14.1`
then this will display - Now using `node v14.19.3` (`npm v6.14.17`)
after I did

```
yarn install
```

and it was a success

Comment: hi, this is was the answer for me

Answer (score 6):

i have been facing the same problem for a while now on rails app, and was solved by upgrading webpacker:

```
# check your Gemfile for version restrictions
bundle update webpacker

# overwrite your changes to the default install files and revert any unwanted changes from the install
rails webpacker:install

# yarn 1 instructions
yarn upgrade @rails/webpacker --latest
yarn upgrade webpack-dev-server --latest
```

see: https://github.com/rails/webpacker#upgrading

props to chase439 : https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2447

Answer (score 6):

As for me, the issue was resolved after upgrading to the latest v7.0.1. Based on this [github issue](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/3194), node-sass team has fixed it in version 7.0 and above.

I'm using node v16.13.2 and on Apple M1 Chip.

Answer (score 5):

my solution use node v10.19.0

https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/1149#issuecomment-552705885

> Had a similar problem with /node_modules/node-sass: Command failed on
> building my application, which also occurred within the last week
> without any updates on my end.
>
> Had a look at the node-sass docs and the node version on the server
> and it was using node v12.13.0 and the version of node-sass was 4.9.x.
>
> in the node-sass release docs it lists that for node v12 you need to
> have node-sass v4.12 and up.
>
> Updating node-sass version corrected the build for me, hope it helps
> for you too.
>
> node Release docs: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases

Comment: I encountered this issue trying to replicate a site on EC2 - this made me think to double check I had installed the same version of Node that was used to develop the site. I had not.

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting this error while trying to deploy your project on Heroku, these steps worked for me:

On 16 December 2021, Heroku [changed](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2306) the Node version to 16.13.1 (which was previously 12.16.2). Since we have dependencies such as `node-sass v4.14.1` which requires Node v14, we need to specify the Node version Heroku should use.

- First, we need to use multiple buildpacks, which will specify to
  install Node first then install Ruby ([Read more from Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#installed-binaries)).

**Please make you install them in the order below**

> ```
> $ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs
> $ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/ruby
> ```

- Verify that the buildpacks are installed

> ```
> $ heroku buildpacks
> ```
>
> ---
>
> 1. heroku/nodejs
> 2. heroku/ruby

- If buildpacks are not in the order above, remove each of them and add
  them again. If, for example, `ruby` comes first, you can just remove
  it, then add it again as below.

> ```
> $ heroku buildpacks:remove heroku/ruby
> ```
>
> Add it again
>
> ```
> $ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/ruby
> ```
>
> Now you should have the correct ordering.

- Specify correct Node version in package.json ([As referenced on stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70396981/8050183))

> ```
> {
>   ...
>   "engines": {
>     "node": "14.x"
>   },
>   ...
> }
> ```

- Make sure to run `$ yarn install` to update your dependencies based on the new Node version.

> This happens because your application contains a Yarn lockfile
> `yarn.lock` which does not match the dependencies in `package.json`.
> This can happen if you use npm to install or update a dependency
> instead of Yarn.

- If applicable commit to Git and Deploy!

I found this solution in this [article](https://dev.to/axelmukwena/heroku-error-nodemodulesnode-sass-command-failed-4mn8) and it worked for me, hope I could help someone

Answer (score 3):

Install `node-sass` globally with `yarn`

Or
Add `node-sass` to your project

Comment: Hi @Eren
I have tried it but it gives me same error

Comment: @Adil I downloaded the sample in this repo [StoreFront](https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront) and simply called `npm install` did not throw an error. Actually I'm not a yarn expert but you can also try clean yarn's cached and globally downloaded files and re- install `yarn`. By the way I'm using macOs Catalina.

Comment: Thanks for your info. Actually I used nodejs with magento2 in other way and it is working fine

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by installing the python 2.7 version on windows os.I had Python 3 installed before. This error happens because of the python version 3.

Answer (score 3):

On top of the suggested resolutions, I've found that sometimes `yarn.lock` has a `node-gyp` locked version for `node-sass`.
When I changed it from **3.8.0** to **8.4.1** everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to update your PATH environment variable to point to Python2 instead of Python3 (remove the Python3 directory from PATH)

Answer (score 2):

**For macOS users**

If you need to use `node-gyp` from within `npm` (e.g. through `npm install`), you will have to install node-gyp (either globally with `-g` or to a predictable location) and tell `npm` where the new version is.

In my case, turns out my project defaulted to using `node-gyp v3.8.0` to building my project's modules.

To remedy that, I ran the following commands:

```
npm config set node_gyp /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp
npm install
```

I hope this is insightful for anyone going through the same.

Answer (score 2):

I was using `"node-sass": "^4.13.1"` in my package.json. I updated to `"node-sass": "6.0.0"` and it worked. My Node.js version is `v16.14.0`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when containerising a VueJs app.
I was using the node:15.12.0-alpine tag as base image before but the issue was fixed once I changed to the full node image (node:15.12.0) that uses debian-stretch.

Answer (score 1):

> It's failing because python3 is used here. Create a .npmrc file in the
> project folder containing python = "/usr/bin/python2.7" and install.
> According to link, python 3.x.x is not yet supported. – NaceurBouhamed
> Feb 25 '20 at 12:28

****python = "**localpath**/python27/python.exe"

RESOLVED

Answer (score 1):

TBH my problem was that I tried to "npm install angular-cli" instead of "npm install @angular/cli", hope this helps other dummies like me :)

Answer (score 1):

For Vue Storefront 1, you can try using node version 10.16.0 and it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

## For Rails Users

For me this was an easy fix. If you are using nvm, just make sure you have the correct node version installed and in use.

Steps:

1. Check your node version `node -v`
2. If the node version is different to the one your rails project is using then update (example using node 16 but project is using node 14), run `nvm use 14`
3. run `yarn install`

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

detect your current npm config python path by run:
`$ npm config get python`

if it another from your current python path, so change it by run:
`$ npm config set python=<YOUR_PYTHON_DIR_PATH>`

(for example in my machine it's: `C:\python311`)

Answer (score 0):

With gulp I got "Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 12.x

Found bindings for the following environments:

- Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment."

So I ran `npm rebuild node-sass` and that worked! Then npm install and everything went ok.

Answer (score 0):

Got very strange solutions around after reading the heroku logs.

Initially I have added buildpacks into this order:
heroku/ruby
heroku/nodejs

[image]

But after looking into the complete log and error i have change the order:
heroku/nodejs
heroku/ruby

[image]

After that precompile works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me a day after upgrading node. I had to revert to a lower node version. I had upgraded to 16.13.2 from 14.15.4

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was using a newer version of Node (16 via nvm) than my current version of node-sass (4.9) supported. Falling back to Node 10 worked to relieve the issue. Ângelo Polotto's answer has a good compatibility chart to follow.

Answer (score 0):

From personal perspective you had better to use:

```
 yarn add axios
```

Answer (score 0):

if your project has **.nvmrc** file, then install/use nodejs listed on that file.

inside my .nvmrc file, it's listed v8, so I'm just installing node v8.

.nvmrc is specifying or locking your application with a specific node.js version.