# Heroku fails during build with Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, node-sass

Ruby 2.7.4
Rails 6.1.4.1

*note: in `package.json` the `engines` key is missing in my app*

Heroku fails during build with this error

this commit is an empty commit on top of exactly a SHA that I was successful at pushing yesterday (I've checked twice now) so I suspect this is a platform problem or somehow the node-sass got deprecated or yanked yesterday?

how can I fix this?

```
remote:        
remote:        ERROR in ./app/javascript/require_bootstrap.scss
remote:        Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
remote:        ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
**remote:        Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)**
remote:        For more information on which environments are supported please see:
remote:        https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1
remote:            at module.exports (/tmp/build_1c436dcf/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:13:13)
remote:            at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_1c436dcf/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
remote:            at Module._compile (/tmp/build_1c436dcf/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
remote:            at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Heroku switched the default Node from 14 to 16 in Dec 2021 for the Ruby buildpack .

Heroku updated the `heroku/ruby` buildpack Node version from Node 14 to Node 16 (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2306) which is not compatible with the version of Node Sass locked in at the Webpack version you're likely using.

To fix it do these two things:

1. Specify the 14.x Node version in `package.json`.

```json
# In package.json
{
  # ...
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
  # ...
}
```

2. Add the `heroku/nodejs` buildpack *before* the `heroku/ruby` buildpack. You can do this in the web interface or with the command line. Here is the command for the CLI:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs -i 1 -a YOUR-APP-NAME
```

With the NodeJS buildpack running first, it will look at the `package.json` file and respect that when choosing which version of Node to install. Then the Ruby buildpack will run and since a version of Node already exists it will just use that and everything should work as before.

Comment: Boom! Your answer is better than Heroku's (who said the same thing). Also they pointed me to this Dec 2021 change ... who knew... https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2306

Comment: Running only step 2 fixed the problem for me. I didn't need to specify 14.x Node in my `package.json`

Comment: Currently the `heroku/nodejs` package defaults to Node 14, but that will change at some point just like the `heroku/ruby` buildpack did. If you specify that you require Node 14 (as step 1 describes above), you will not have trouble when they change the default to Node 16.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes. Some are improving lives through answers like this! I was completely clueless and the error message made me think I missed up something in my branches, although I'm sure I haven't. Thanks so much!

Comment: I had the same problem, the app depends on node 14.x.x but Heroku installed 16.x.x. Keep in mind that in the Heroku admin panel, the `heroku/nodejs` buildpack **MUST** be located before the `heroku/ruby` buildpack.

Comment: I had the same problem. To make it work, I had to remove all heroku buildpacks first, then add (in this order) the `heroku/nodejs` and then `heroku/ruby`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this problem was quite different in my situation. Updating the webpacker gem from 3.5.5 to 5.4.3 made the error disappear.