# gyp ERR! build error gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2 when pushing on heroku

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, npm, heroku

When pushing my rails project on Heroku i get:

remote:        gyp ERR! build error

remote:        gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2

remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_47b2dcad/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)

remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
remote:        gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1097-aws

remote:        gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_47b2dcad/bin/node" "/tmp/build_47b2dcad/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="

remote:        gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_47b2dcad/node_modules/node-sass

remote:        gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.1

remote:        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0

remote:        gyp ERR! not ok

remote:        Build failed with error code: 1

remote:

remote:  !

remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.

remote:  !

remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.

does somebody know how to help me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem with node v16 and nodes-sass. (Was using v14 on development machine)

Perhaps this answer will help

[Heroku fails during build with Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70393094/heroku-fails-during-build-with-error-node-sass-does-not-yet-support-your-curren)