# Error when installing a chart library in ReactJS @16.13.1

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, django

I am trying to install a chart library in a react app, but I am getting the same error. I am using version @16.13.1 for ReactJS, for python @3.8.2 and django @3.2.10 and "@material-ui/core": "4.9.14". Could you help me, please, to find out which is the problem and which library I should use with the versions listed above? Thank you

```
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
```

Comment: This error is not related to Python. And i doubt if it's your version of your NodeJS which causes this issue. I recommend you to try upgrading/downgrading your NodeJS version and try to install your packages.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue. Apparently I had to reinstall node-sass. I followed this solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60394291/error-node-modules-node-sass-command-failed]. I don't understand the connection, as I am new in building an app with react and django.

Comment: Don't use `node-sass`, it's deprecated. Switch to just `sass`.